# Getting MethodInfo for protected and public methods only?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get the `MethodInfo` for `protected` and `public` methods only?

Comment: For some reason the answers do not state that `IsFamily` refers to `protected` (but not `protected internal`) members - see "[`MethodBase.IsFamily`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.isfamily)" for more details.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no direct way. The thing you can do is check `IsFamily` and `IsPublic` flag of `MethodInfo`:

```
minfo = b.GetType().GetMethod("publicProtectedMember", 
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
if (minfo.IsFamily || minfo.IsPublic)
{
  string s = fd.Member();
}
```

Comment: `GetMethods` not just `GetMethod` I guess

Answer (score 4):

Well, can't you just get all `MemberInfo`s and filter them out by `IsFamily` and `IsPublic` properties?

Comment: This answer is much better when compared to the others in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

var methods = foo
    .GetType()
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(m => m.IsFamily || m.IsPublic);
```